# UICollectionView with variant itemsize and multiple section

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

[image]
How do I implement the layout showed in the image using UICollectionView?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
- you have to create a **UICollectionReusableView class** for section:
ex: ReusableView.h

```
@interface ReusableView : UICollectionReusableView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *headerImage; // example of header content
@end
```

ReusableView.m

```
@implementation ReusableView
- (void)awakeFromNib {

// Initialization code
}
@end
```

-in ReusableView.xib you have to delete the default view and add the UICollectionReusableView from ObjectLibrary and the you add your image or label or whatever and in AttributeInspector on identifier you have to write your IdentifierName (the same things you have to make for cell)

- for cell you have to use the **UICollectionTableViewCell class** and follow the same steps from UICollectionReusableView.

Second:

- in ViewController.h you have to use some delegates: `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>`
- in ViewController.m you have to use this methods from delegation, but first in viewDidLoad method you have to implement this:

  ```
  [yourCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ReusableView" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionReusable"]; //collection identifier is: @"CollectionReusable"

  [yourCollectionView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];
  ```
- for **section** you have to implement this methods from delegate:

  ```
  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  return CGSizeZero;
  }

  - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section; // here you return number of sections 



  - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  ```

  {
  headerView = nil;

  headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionReusable" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [headerView.headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[listOfSymbolsObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];

  ```
  return headerView;
  ```

  }

-for **cells** you have to implement this methods from delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Hope it helps you ! :)

Comment: You can mark your question as answered :)  Check the star and my check to make it green. @Evan